# calculating stack memory in c

Tags: c, heap-memory, stack-memory

I'm trying to calculate stack memory used in my program.

1. should i add 4 for each integer i have defined?
2. what about something like char str[128], shoudld i add 128 or 129?
3. ```
   #define ARRAY1_LIMIT 200
   #define ARRAY2_LIMIT 100

   char* array1[ARRAY1_LIMIT];
   char* array2[ARRAY2_LIMIT];

   int i = 0;
   int j = 0

   array1[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*5);
   array2[j] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
   ```

I know that the heap memory is 5+15 = 15, but i don't know how to calculate the stack memory? is it 200 + 100?

Comment: This is not a valid program.

Comment: Can you describe the problem you're actually attempting to solve a little bit better? Why are you trying to calculate the stack memory used? Are you trying to ensure it's reasonable?

Comment: 1) "should i add 4 for each integer i have defined?" - I don't understand that: why do you need to add four to each integer? If you do so, you'll be accessing a different element. 2) "what about something like char str[128], shoudld i add 128 or 129?" - add 128 or 129... _to what_?? Anyway, what's the difference here?

Comment: it's just a part of my program. i have two arrays of char* pointers  and I have to allocate memory at each pointer. I just have to find out how much stack memory I used to answer a question no other purpose.

Comment: @ForceBru i mean to add to the stack memory I have, not to the acutal integer. since each integer takes 4 bytes.

Comment: i'm just trying to see how much stack memory this part of my program needs.

Comment: `5+15 = 15` Really?

Comment: sorry i meant 20.

Comment: sounds like a test. 'How much stack memory is used by this program, how much heap?'. As you can see nobody ever does that in real life, hence the surprised comments. BTW you example uses no stack

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing anything more than simply trying to learn about stack usage and how variable allocations affect it, you'll want to use a stack depth analysis tool. Such a tool can help you determine if your program could possibly overflow its stack under any possible sequence of events (excepting unexpected or unbounded recursion). You can write your own (I have, in C#, for embedded programs compiled in C for M16C and MIPS targets using GCC and IAR compilers), but it's really complex and not something for beginners to attempt.

Look for a "stack usage analyzer" or "stack usage analysis tool" for your particular processor and toolchain (e.g. x86/x64/ARM/etc and GCC/VisualStudio/IAR/etc).

If you're using GCC, you may be able to use the `-fstack-usage` option, but that only gives you the maximum stack usage on a per-function basis. By itself that's not terribly helpful, since to verify that a program won't blow its stack, you have to recursively walk the calltree to see what the maximum stack depth could be at any level of the call tree. If you also use the `-Wstack-usage` option, you can get a warning if any subprogram's stack usage can possibly exceed a specified stack depth, which is more useful than the information you get with merely the `-fstack-usage` option.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to work out the amount of 'space allocated to those variables in a function, use the `sizeof()` operator.
Notice that the arrays are arrays of `char *` which are pointers to characters not characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    size_t total=0;

    size_t first_array_size=sizeof(char *[200]);
    printf("first array: %zu\n",first_array_size);
    total+=first_array_size;
    size_t second_array_size=sizeof(char *[100]);
    printf("second array: %zu\n",second_array_size);
    total+=second_array_size;

    size_t int_size=sizeof(int);
    printf("int size: %zu * 2 = %zu\n",int_size,int_size*2);
    total+=int_size*2;


    printf("total=%zu\n",total);

    return 0;
}
```

Typical output (on a 64-bit architecture):

```
first array: 1600
second array: 800
int size: 4 * 2 = 8
total=2408
```

Results may vary.

Footnote: It's also worth understanding that the amount of space allocated to the stack frame may be greater.
For example arguments passed in are typically copied to the stack as is the return value along with a pointer representing the execution point to return to after the function is called.
There's also the complexity of alignment. For example on many modern machines space may be left between variables to make sure they're aligned. However optimizations may take some of that space back depending on how it re-orders the variables. It's also possible that values (particularly integer values) may be allocated to registers and not take up space on the stack.

Finally an implementation could in principle allocate the arrays on the heap. That's certainly a possible implementation for variable length arrays but I'm not aware of it being strictly disallowed for fixed size arrays.

Comment: so they are type char which is only one byte, why are they multiple by 8?

Comment: @sophie96 - `char` is one byte, but `char*` is a pointer (possibly 4 or 8 bytes).

Comment: @ Bo Persson Thank you